# Having margin on my boostrap column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm a beginner to bootstrap. Why does my main-box ( `ng-view` ) have margins?

I have tried setting zero padding to `.container` and zero margin to `.row`, but it doesn't work.

Is it because of AngularJS ng-view?

Could you take a look at it please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- developed by Min Htet Oo -->
    <title>gym</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .main-box {
        margin-top: 50px;
        background-color: aqua;
      }
      .container-fluid {
        padding: 0!important;
      }
      .container {
        padding: 0!important;
      }
      .row {
        margin: 0!important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">blar blar blar :3</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="#/item">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#/sale">Stock</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 main-box" ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment.I didn't know that I can't get full width div box with container.I have changed container to container-fluid and it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `ng-view` won't affect your CSS. It's likely due to your `div` or `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `.main-box` class to fill the entire width, then you need to change your `.container` class to `.container-fluid.` It is bootstrap that is your problem.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Comment: "For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience". This is beginner knowledge...

Comment: "However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on."

Comment: That would mean that after he learns the basics move on, but hes still in the basics.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment.I didn't know that I can't get full width div box with container.I have changed container to container-fluid and it solves my problem.